# Laravel: How to retrieve this nested model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel I have `ModelA`, `ModelB` and `ModelC`.  `ModelA` has many `ModelB`.  `ModelB` has many `ModelC`.  I want to retrieve all ModelC for a selection of ModelA.  How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
$models = ModelC::with(['modelB','modelB.modelA' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('owner', 123);
}])->get();
```

But the first query in that case is `select * from model_c`.  Obviously not the result I am looking for.

Comment: What's the query you want in raw SQL?

Comment: You might be looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: When you use eager loading it isn't going to to create just one query, it will create a query for each relationship you want to load. The idea of eager/lazy loading is to get around the n+1 problem. The above should result in 3 (possibly 4) queries.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are looking to get back from your query. You are not happy with select * from model_c but you question sounds like you want everything from model_c but only for those linked to selection of model_a via model_b?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you were received 100 objects from the database, and each record had 1 associated model (i.e. belongsTo). Using an ORM would produce 101 queries by default; one query for the original 100 records, and additional query for each record if you accessed the related data on the model object. In pseudo code, let’s say you wanted to list all published authors that have contributed a post. From a collection of posts (each post having one author) you could get a list of author names like so:

```
$posts = Post::published()->get(); // one query

$authors = array_map(function($post) {
    // Produces a query on the author model
    return $post->author->name;
}, $posts);
```

We are not telling the model that we need all the authors, so an individual query happens each time we get the author’s name from the individual Post model instances.

***Eager Loading***

As I mentioned, ORMs “lazy” load associations. If you intend to use the associated model data you can trim that 101 query total to 2 queries using eager loading. You just need to tell the model what you need it to load eagerly.

Here’s an example from the Rails Active Record guide on using eager loading. As you can see, the concept is quite similar to Laravel’s eager loading concept.

```
$posts = Post::with('author')->limit(100)->get();
```

I find that I receive better understanding by exploring ideas from a wider perspective. The Active Record documentation covers some examples that can further help the idea resonate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with nested `whereHas` calls as follows:

```
$models = modelC::whereHas('modelB', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('modelA', function ($query) {
        $query->where('owner', 123);
    });
})->get();
```

Laravel to the rescue, yet again!